# Docusign error: "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: php, rest, docusignapi

We're using the Docusign RestAPI (PHP SDK) from our app and it works great. Authentication mode is JWT. I want to use all the code I've written on a different subdomain, but I get this error:

`API call to https://account.docusign.com/oauth/token failed: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Both domains, my-domain.com and new.my-domain.com have SSL certs installed. What do I do now? What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new subdomain was operating on a different version of PHP. I added the cert paths to that php.ini file and it works as it should now.

Answer (score 0):

The [DocuSign public certificates](https://www.docusign.com/trust/compliance/public-certificates) page lists all certificates.

Scroll down and look for this:

Install the certificate on your server where you are running the code from.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate, please? If I try to import, IIS rejects it. If I do a "complete certificate request" no errors are thrown but nothing shows up. I can see it in the certificate store, but not in IIS.

Comment: I think it would work best if you contact customer support where they can work with you to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the standard set of trusted root certs installed in PHP?

This [article](https://kb.ucla.edu/articles/how-do-i-update-root-certificates-in-apachephpcurl-environment) may help you.